# Adding a left join reduces the number of rows returned

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, oracle12c

I'm trying to debug the following piece of SQL, the last segment of which is a left join. When I run the query below, I get 8 rows, but if I remove the last left join I get 13 results. It's my understanding that a left join should never reduce the number of rows returned, how is this possible?

```
SELECT  *
  FROM
(
  SELECT   A.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID,
      D.QUESTION_ANSWER_ID   ,
      D.QUESTION_REPLICA_ID
    FROM ADMINISTRATIONS A,
      ADMINISTRATION_DETAILS D
    WHERE A.ADMINISTRATION_ID = 4326509
      AND A.ADMINISTRATION_ID =D.ADMINISTRATION_ID
)
T
  JOIN QUESTION_ANSWERS QA
  ON QA.QUESTION_ANSWER_ID=T.QUESTION_ANSWER_ID
  JOIN QUESTIONS Q
  ON Q.QUESTION_ID=QA.QUESTION_ID
  JOIN ANSWERS A
  ON A.ANSWER_ID=QA.ANSWER_ID
  JOIN PHRASES PA
  ON PA.PHRASE_ID=A.PHRASE_ID
  JOIN QUESTIONNAIRE_DETAILS QD
  ON QD.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID      = T.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID
    AND QD.QUESTION_ID        =QA.QUESTION_ID
    AND QD.QUESTION_REPLICA_ID=1
  LEFT JOIN QUESTIONNAIRE_DETAILS D
  ON D.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID      = T.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID
    AND D.QUESTION_ID        =QA.QUESTION_ID
    AND D.QUESTION_REPLICA_ID=T.QUESTION_REPLICA_ID
  LEFT JOIN ANSWER_VALUES AV
  ON AV.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID=T.QUESTIONNAIRE_ID
    AND AV.QUESTION_ID  =QA.QUESTION_ID
    AND AV.ANSWER_ID    =QA.ANSWER_ID
  LEFT JOIN ADMINISTRATION_DETAILS AD
  ON AD.ADMINISTRATION_ID     =4326509
    AND AD.QUESTION_ANSWER_ID =T.QUESTION_ANSWER_ID
    AND AD.QUESTION_REPLICA_ID=T.QUESTION_REPLICA_ID
  LEFT JOIN ADMINISTRATION_OPEN_ANSWERS O
  ON O.ADMINISTRATION_ID     =AD.ADMINISTRATION_ID
    AND O.QUESTION_ANSWER_ID =AD.QUESTION_ANSWER_ID
    AND O.QUESTION_REPLICA_ID=AD.QUESTION_REPLICA_ID
  LEFT JOIN --the offending left join that causes me to get 8 results instead of 13
    (
      SELECT 1 AS destination_id FROM dual
    )
    RD
  ON RD.DESTINATION_ID       = 0
    AND O.QUESTION_ANSWER_ID = 1328 --If I remove just this line, I get 13 results
    ;
```

What seems to be happening is that a check is being forced where rows with no entries in table O are being removed, but I can't find any piece of documentation explaining this as expected behaviour.

I am running Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Are you removing just one line or the entire `left join`?

Comment: what happens if you `SELECT 0 AS destination_id FROM dual` instead of 1?

Comment: @GordonLinoff performing either operation gets it to return the correct number of rows, even though the left join isn't even matching any of the rows in my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in the optimizer, if I roll it back with

```
ALTER SESSION SET optimizer_features_enable='11.2.0.4';
```

it begins to behave correctly.

Edit: Here is a more permanent solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER revert_optimizer AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
  DECLARE
    CMD VARCHAR2(100) := 'alter session set optimizer_features_enable="11.2.0.4"';
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CMD;
  END revert_optimizer;
```